# Eclipse CDT creating statically linked shared library

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I'm using Eclipse Kepler to create a shared library, statically linked with runtime/boost.

For this I have the following command line in GCC C++ Compiler window:

```
g++ -IPATH_TO_BOOST_INC -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -Bstatic -fPIC
```

And the following line for Linker :

```
-LBOOST_LIB_PATH -shared
```

My library compiles without any issues, but when I check it's content I see that it's still dynamically linked. What am I doing wrong? Can anybody point the issue out to me?

Thanks a lot in advance,
BR, Dmitry

Comment: Hmmm... `shared` implies `dynamic` last I checked.

Comment: Is there any possibility to have a shared object with statically linked runtime/boost ? Like /MT option in VS ?

Comment: Are you asking for a shared library that statically links Boost to your shared library?  I **think** the answer is no.  With any luck, someone with more expertise may chime in with a way to do that.  I think Boost's own configuration assumes a fully-static or fully-dynamic link model, and not a blend (and I think I understand why).

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'd like to have. I'm able to compile an executable statically linked with Boost, and now I'm trying to do the same thing for .so. Do you think it's impossible? What is best way to distibute my application over the users?